# RETICULATE: py_available returns FALSE

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I created a virtual environment using conda.

```
> library(reticulate)
> use_condaenv("env_ret")



> py_discover_config()
python:         C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\env_ret\python.exe
libpython:      C:/Program Files/Anaconda3/envs/env_ret/python38.dll
pythonhome:     C:\PROGRA~1\ANACON~1\envs\env_ret
version:        3.8.0 (default, Nov  6 2019, 16:00:02) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:\PROGRA~1\ANACON~1\envs\env_ret\lib\site-packages\numpy
numpy_version:  1.17.3

python versions found: 
 C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\env_ret\python.exe
 C:\PROGRA~1\ANACON~1\envs\env_ret\python.exe
 C:\PROGRA~1\ANACON~1\python.exe
 C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\python.exe
 C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\my-env\python.exe
```

But then, i cannot use it:

```
> py_config()
Error in py_initialize(config$python, config$libpython, config$pythonhome,  : 
  Py_CompileString - The specified procedure could not be found.

> py_available()
[1] FALSE
```

RSTUDIO version: 1.2.1335 
R version: 3.6.1 
Python: 3.7.1

Thanks

Comment: I am also having the same problem. My situation is that `reticulate` has stopped working after I moved some directories around (from Dropbox to home folder) and perhaps that broke some paths. Whatever the case may be `python` works on command line but not from reticulate.